# Returning value printed by button during Flutter integration test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a simple app that has a screen with a button. When this button is pressed the login screen pops up; It has two text fields (one for email and one for password), and a button. When the button is pressed, the credentials are authenticated and the json containing the info is printed to the console (I haven't implemented the whole functionality of the button yet since this will take a long time).
I'm running a group of integration tests to see if the app runs normally, which includes having the json printed to the console. That, however, doesn't happen, but it does when I debug the app. Is there any way to print that json to the console during an integration test?

These are my tests:

```
test('Button renders', () async {
      expect(await driver.getText(enterTextFinder), "Enter");
    });

test('Button taps', () async {
  await driver.tap(enterButtonFinder);

  expect(await driver.getText(acceptTextFinder), "Accept");
});

test('Enter credentials', () async {
  await driver.tap(emailFieldFinder);
  await driver.enterText(email);

  await driver.tap(passFieldFinder);
  await driver.enterText(password);
});

test('Perform login', () async {
  await driver.tap(acceptButtonFinder);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to update the state and check if the state changed? You can pass a mock state for example to not require full implementation. Trying to grab print/log output seems flaky at best to me.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, that does make sense. I was printing because during debugging it was the quickest thing to implement and I could see the json, and I guess I got attached to it. Your suggestion will probably be better for testing. Thank you!

Comment: Will you get log for just clicking the `acceptButton` (meaning `email` and `password` are not entered)?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian, no, nothing happens at all during the test when I click it in any way